# How to replace a new line for each 10 number of commas

Tags: notepad++

I have a set of numbers separated by commas in the notepad++ document.
 I want to set a new line after every 10 number of commas/ or 10 no of numbers. How do i do this?

have this list

```
19406,20894,21138,21140,21142,21775,22097,34420,35455,35873,35892,35965,37373,37378,37380,37391,37398,37404,37406,37452,37454,37456,37849,37861,38080,39039,42445
```

need below..

```
19406,20894,21138,21140,21142,21775,22097,34420,35455,35873,
35892,35965,37373,37378,37380,37391,37398,37404,37406,37452,
37454,37456,37849,37861,38080,39039,42445
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:\d+,){10}\K`
- Replace with: `\n`  # you may use `\r\n` for windows linebreak
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       # beginning of line
(?:     # non capture group
  \d+   # 1 or more digits
  ,     # a comma
){10}   # end group, appears 10 times
\K      # forget all we have seen until this position
```